# C++ contains relationship - always need initializer list?

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I want an object to contain another (a "has-a" relationship).  Must the contained object always be created in the initializer list?  I want to avoid using pointers.  If I know I have to use an initializer list then that's fine.

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
    private:
        int ii;
    public:
        A(int anIi): ii(anIi) {};
        int GetBilly() {return ii;}
        void billy() 
        { 
            for (int jj = 0; jj < ii; ++jj) 
            {
                std::cout << "Billy!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
}; 

class B {
    private:

    public:
        A mya;
        B(int wantIi): mya(A(wantIi)) {
        }
        void snoodly() {
            int ii = mya.GetBilly();
            for (int jj = 0; jj < 2*ii; ++jj)
            {
                std::cout << "Silly!" << std::endl;
            }

        }
};

int main () {
    B myB = B(5);
    myB.snoodly();
    myB.mya.snerdly();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "must"? You can leave it to the compiler to default-initialize it if you prefer.

Comment: In C++11, you can also use a *non-static data member initializer*. If an NSDMI does not exist and the data member does not occur in the member initializer list, it will be default-initialized.

Comment: `mya(A(wantIi))` is redundant, `mya(wantIi)` is sufficient. Similarly, `B myB = B(5);` is redundant, `B myB(5);` is sufficient.

Comment: Consider making constructors `explicit` if they require only one argument of a fundamental type (like `int`). Otherwise, you might inadvertently convert to the class type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

A contained object (CO) can be created by default initialisation, by a class member declaration initialiser, or in the constructor's initialiser list. The latter two would be needed if the CO had no default constructor or the default value was unwanted.

If the CO's value is known and available at the time the container is constructed then it is convenient to initialise the CO to that value.

If not, it is perfectly reasonably to initialise the CO to some harmless default value by one of the above mechanisms, and then later set its value by assignment or by method calls, depending on what it supports.

So my answer is: not really, although it may be quite convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If the class has no default constructor then you have to use the mem initializer list to initialize the corresponding object.
Or you can initializer the object in the class definition.